# Change Listview textsize with seekbar using custom layout without using getview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, seekbar

I am trying to make a bible app. I'm using listview to show verses..in my listview i used a textview in a customlayout for the listview's list items, I put a seekbar below the listview so the users can adjust the font size. I solved this but my problem is only the first item adjusts when I use the seekbar. I saw some posts but they used getView method, I didn't use that..Please help, I'm new in android development

Main Activity code:

```
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    int Blast;
    @Override

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

        TextView shopName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_version);
        prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
      ed.putFloat("fontsize", ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_version)).getTextSize());
        ed.commit();

       // myList.setSelection(1);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_version)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, seekBar.getProgress());


    }
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_version)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,seekBar.getProgress());
    }
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                  boolean fromUser){

            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_version)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,progress);

        Blast = progress;

    }
});
```

public void viewAll1(){

```
    Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllData2();

    String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.item_version};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, cursor, from, to, 0);



ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

}

item_layout.xml

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="Large Text"
android:id="@+id/item_version"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textIsSelectable="false"
android:typeface="serif"

android:paddingStart="20dp" />
```

Comment: What do you mean only the first item adjusts?

Comment: when i adjust the seekbar, only the first item change it's textsize, please help :(

Comment: Like the first item in the `ListView`?

Comment: yes :( , it only adjust the first item or the item where you scroll from listview, my goal is to adjust all the items simultaneously when i adjust the seekbar

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should use `getView` method, it won't bite, seriously. `getView` let's you tweak the way each view in your `ListView` is displayed. The `TextView` with id `item_version` exists inside the `ListView`, so `findViewById` won't work. The only way to get a reference to that TextView is using `getView`.

You should read a tutorial about ListViews and adapters, so that you understand [how getView works and how to not shoot yourself in the foot while using it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70), but here's a little help to get you started.
Override `SimpleCursorAdapter` to hold an extra attribute for font size. Something like:

```
float textSize = 14f;

public void setTextSize(float size){
    textSize = size;
}
```

Then, right below that line, override`getView`, so that for every view you do something like:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_version);
textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
```

Your activity should hold a reference to your adapter. When progress changes, here's how you can update your `ListView`

```
adapter.setTextSize(progress);
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Comment: I followed your advice, however when i drag the seekbar, nothing is happening, no errors,. why is that?

Comment: could you post the code in `getView` and `onProgressChanged`?

Comment: @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);
        TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_version);
        //((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_version)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
    title.setTextSize(textSize);
    title.setText(days[position]);
return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

Comment: on progresschanged: adapter.setTextSize(progress);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: The problem is, once again, that you are don't understand how `ListView` and `getView` work. Your app could display hundreds of verses, however, your screen can only display about seven of them at once, right? Then, you only need 7 views in memory and recycle them as the user scrolls down. This is where `getView` comes in handy, it does something like get the View that my list should display at this position. You must return the view that you want to show, instead of calling super. See that argument `convertView`? That's a recycled view, you only inflate a view if convertView is null.

Comment: What should i do sir?

Comment: return the inflated view instead of `super.getView`. only inflate if `convertView` is null, otherwise get your `TextView` from `convertView` modify it and return that view,